# React native error on view pager adding in iOS android works fine how to resolve it?

Tags: react-native, android-viewpager

```
"@react-native-community/viewpager": "^2.0.2",
```

The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/innoappstech/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/base-bdidefvmpxcbkoesztljqiocxpqn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-viewpager.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ReactViewPagerManager.o /Users/innoappstech/Desktop/projects/base/node_modules/@react-native-community/viewpager/ios/ReactViewPagerManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

As I need it for scrollview and it works in android only this version. So getting error on iOS. SO anybody can provide me solution. I tried so many things and changing pod files dependencies and other things but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able resolve the issue using the latest version 5.0.11.

```
"@react-native-community/viewpager": "^5.0.11",
```

But this package has been deprecated.
And a new package is available at [react-native-pager-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pager-view)